# using overloaded << operator in another << overload in a different class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, operator-keyword

So here's the problem. I have a class B where I have overloaded the << operator and a class A where the << operator is also overloaded. However, the << overload in class B doesn't seem to be working in the << overload in class A. It simply returns the address of b as if the << overload in class B doesn't exist.

Any help would be very appreciated

```
#pragma once
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

class B {
public:

    B(int x) {
        this->x = x;
    }
    
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, B& b)
    {
        os << "this is B " << b.x;
        return os; 
    }

private:
    int x;
};
```

```
#pragma once
#include <ostream>
#include "B.h"

using namespace std;

class A {
public:

    A(B* b) {
        this->b = b;
        this->x = 0;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, A& a)
    {
        os << a.b << endl; //this doesnt work <============
        os << "this is a " << a.x;
        return os;
    }

private:
    int x;
    B* b;
};
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    B* b = new B(1);
    A* a = new A(b);
    cout << *a << "inside a "<< endl;
    cout << *b << "inside b " <<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
os << a.b // ...
```

`a.b` is not a `B`, for which you defined an overload, look closer at your code:

```
class A {
private:

    B* b;
};
```

That's a `B *`, and not a `B`, and no overload exists for that.

If you want to call the overload here, use `os << (*a.b) // ...`;